# downloading gmail emails

Tags: php, gmail, oauth-2.0

I need to download Gmail emails using php api. there APIs for google. i do not exactly which api to use. i have web application. i have registered my application on google, oauth2.0. at this url [Google Api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). i have downloaded this [php API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.5.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=)
I which there are many services. but not gmail. I do not want to use accessing emails using username and password API. i want to access using the token. which is permanent access token.

Comment: Is using the php api a requirement? You can change the account to pop/imap and use any php imap/pop mail function to get the mails.

Comment: Php is the requirement .  i want to use oauth2.0 as this is the latest .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google support [OAuth authentication for IMAP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview). Use that.

Comment: i need permanent access to user's inbox feeds. i mean my token should not be time limited. could this api will help?